# Jquery UI resizable, get attribute value of image being resized

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface, resize

This is my image:

```
 echo "<img src='articles/$article_id/$image' style='width:inherit;' id='image' data-articleid='$article_id' data-boxid='$box_id'>";
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var startW = 0;
var startH = 0;

$('#image').resizable({
    start : function(event,ui) {
        startW = $(this).outerWidth();
        startH = $(this).outerHeight();
    },
    stop : function(event,ui) {
        w = $(this).outerWidth();
        h = $(this).outerHeight();

        boxid = $(this).attr("data-boxid");
        articleid = $(this).attr("data-articleid");

        $.post("processforms/process_techtools.php", { boxid:boxid, articleid:articleid, width:w, height:h, resize_image_submit:0}, function (data) {     
          $("#progress").hide();             
          $("#success").show().fadeOut(1500);          
        });     
    }
});
});
</script>
```

In the resizable stop function, boxid and articleid return undefined.  How can I get it to see these attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error, `this` keyword represents the parent of the image, not the image it self. So you have two options, you either select `this` and then find the your image underneath. Depending on your markup, this will be solution:

```
boxid = $(this).find("img").attr("data-boxid"); // added find() before calling attr
articleid = $(this).find("img").attr("data-articleid");//added find() before calling attr
```

---

But that an ugly solution. Since JQuery `stop : function(event,ui)`  is actually giving you the element in question in `ui` variable. It's not `ui` per se, it is it's child `ui.originalElement` . So you need to use `$(ui.originalElement).attr();` to access the image.

Therefore, your code should be something like:

```
boxid = $(ui.originalElement).attr("data-boxid"); // use 'ui' NOT 'this'
articleid = $(ui.originalElement).attr("data-articleid");//use 'ui' NOT 'this'
```

Hope that helps.